# Can I add QMainWindow to a stacked widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to switch between MainWindow and QDialog Window by using stacked widgets. Is it possible to add aQMainWindow in a stacked widget?

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 110, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.nextButt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nextButt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 270, 75, 23))
        self.nextButt.setObjectName("nextButt")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hi"))
        self.nextButt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Next"))


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.menuButt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.menuButt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 75, 23))
        self.menuButt.setObjectName("menuButt")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.menuButt.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Menu"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Bye"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    main_win = Ui_MainWindow()
    dialog = Ui_Dialog()
    stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()
    stackedWidget.addWidget(main_win)
    stackedWidget.addWidget(dialog)
    stackedWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But i keep getting error
TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to add what is known as the *form class*. This is a standard python `object` type, and it's used on PyQt as an abstract object "helper" which is able to build the UI on an existing empty QWidget subclass.

What a QStackedWidget expects is a QWidget subclass instead (a QMainWindow, a QDialog, etc). Unfortunately, while you created a QMainWindow instance, you never used it with the `Ui_MainWindow.setupUi()` function, and you didn't even create a QDialog instance.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    mainWindowUi = Ui_MainWindow()
    mainWindowUi.setupUi(mainWindow)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialogUi = Ui_Dialog()
    dialogUi.setupUi(dialog)

    stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    stackedWidget.addWidget(mainWindow)
    stackedWidget.addWidget(dialog)

    mainWindowUi.nextButt.clicked.connect(
        lambda: stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(dialog))
    dialogUi.menuButt.clicked.connect(
        lambda: stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(mainWindow))
    stackedWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Some considerations:

- remember that files generated by `pyuic` should **never** be modified (nor you should try to mimic their behavior); I can assume you've joined their code for simplicity, but if you didn't and that's actually how you're trying to implement your program you must reconsider it: pyuic generated files should **never** be modified (and their code should *not* be added to your scripts), as they should always used as imports; read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);
- a QMainWindow is a very special type of QWidget subclass that should always be used as a *top level* window, not embedded into another widget; if you want to add a child widget, use a standard QWidget ("Widget" in the Designer startup dialog, often referred to as a "form");
- with the above code, you will probably end up with an unusable interface, as the contents of the two child widgets will not be visible unless the top level window is resized; using fixed geometries (position and size) is always discouraged, as it leads to unaccessible or overlapping widgets, and [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) should always be preferred;